# Check if a HttpWebRequest exists in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I have the following declared in my code behind:

```
  private HttpWebRequest req = null;
  private IAsyncResult result = null;
```

I have a a button click event in my code behind called btnUpload:

```
 req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}{1}", pageUrl.ToString(), arguments));
 req.Method = "GET";

 // Start the asynchronous request.
 result = (IAsyncResult)req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RespCallback), null);
```

I then have another button click event on the same page and in the code behind called btnSubmit that has:

```
 if (req == null)
```

The req is always null. How do I access the req and result variables?

Comment: You haven't really shown enough code, but what you've shown looks okay. Are you sure you haven't redeclared `req` as a *local* variable in one of the event handlers?

Comment: @Jon Skeet I assumed the OP's program is an ASP.NET application because of “…click event on the same *page*…”.

Comment: yes it is a asp.net application

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `Page` object instance *does not live* across multiple HTTP requests. This behavior is by design in ASP.NET.

You should look at the [`PageAsyncTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx) class. This [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/09/07/making-asynchronous-calls-to-web-services-during-asp-net-page-processing.aspx) may be useful to learn how to use it.

Comment: so i have a batchprocessor.aspx.cs page and a BGPbatchprocessor.aspx.cs page. The first page is send the async request to the second page. In the blog you mentioned, am I supposed to overwrite OnInit? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

If you're performing an async request, you'll only have access to the result in the callback method `RespCallback`.  You'll also need to pass in the original request into the async call get the response. Take the following example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req;

            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}{1}", pageUrl.ToString(), arguments));
            req.Method = "GET";

            // pass in request so we can retrieve it later
            req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RespCallback), req); 

        }

        void RespCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebRequest originalRequest = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)originalRequest.EndGetResponse(result);

            // response.GetResponseStream()
        }
```

Comment: when I trace and put break points on my callbacks, they never get hit. Why would that happen?

Comment: Well the code above definately works as posted (after replacing the url logic with something valid). Can you verify that the page/resource that you are async requesting is responding? The only thing I can think of is that your page is not responding or you're not actually hitting the code block that is making the request. The code above fires the callback on both a valid page as well as an invalid (404) page.

Answer (score 0):

the web (programming) is stateless (apart from some artificial webforms UI state maintainted by viewstate), which means if you instantiate object in btnUpload_Click it won't be there in another button event. So you either need to recreate object etc e.g. HttpWebRequest in both buttons' events or store results of btnUpload_Click somewhere (in Session for instance) and access it from btnSubmit_click. Also google for ASP.net page lifecycle.
Hope this helps